# How to NUnit test for a method's attribute existence

Tags: c#, attributes, nunit

```
   public interface IMyServer
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [DynamicResponseType]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "info")]
        string ServerInfo();
    }
```

How do I write an NUnit test to prove that the C# interface method has the `[DynamicResponseType]` attribute set on it?

Answer (score 19):

Something like:

```
Assert.IsTrue(Attribute.IsDefined(
            typeof(IMyServer).GetMethod("ServerInfo"),
            typeof(DynamicResponseTypeAttribute)));
```

You could also do something involving generics and delegates or expressions (instead of the string "ServerInfo"), but I'm not sure it is worth it.

For `[WebGet]`:

```
WebGetAttribute attrib = (WebGetAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(
    typeof(IMyServer).GetMethod("ServerInfo"),
    typeof(WebGetAttribute));
Assert.IsNotNull(attrib);
Assert.AreEqual("info", attrib.UriTemplate);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  

One more item... is there a way to test that the [WebGet(UriTemplate = "info")] attributes UriTemplate is set to "info"?

Comment: I was using different syntax to do the same thing. This answer is a little cleaner so I'm going to switch to that. Thanks for posting!